# How to add values to Request.Form collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, httprequest, formcollection

I need to add values to Request.Form collection, but i don't understand how to initialize `HttpRequest` instance with specified form values. I tried to override `Initialize` method in controller and initialize `HttpRequest` like this:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
   var requestField = typeof (HttpRequestWrapper).GetField("_httpRequest", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                               BindingFlags.Instance);
   var responseField = typeof(HttpResponseWrapper).GetField("_httpResponse", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);


   var req = (HttpRequest) requestField.GetValue(requestContext.HttpContext.Request);
   var res = (HttpResponse)responseField.GetValue(requestContext.HttpContext.Response);
//**************** HERE I TRY TO INITIZLIZE FORM COLLECTION WITH MY VALUE 'additional_form_value' but nothing  
   var newReq = new HttpRequest(null, req.Url.ToString(), "?additional_form_value=test");
   newReq.RequestType = "POST";
//***************


   var r = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(newReq, res)), requestContext.RouteData);


   base.Initialize(r);
}
```

Is any way to add new items to `Request.Form` Collection?

EDIT:

when i tried that approach I got an exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.):

```
NameValueCollection oQuery = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
oQuery = (NameValueCollection)requestContext.HttpContext.Request.GetType().GetField("_form", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(requestContext.HttpContext.Request); //exception here
PropertyInfo oReadable = oQuery.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
oReadable.SetValue(oQuery, false, null);
oQuery["foo"] = "bar";
oReadable.SetValue(oQuery, true, null);
```

Comment: On which line do you get this exception?

Comment: second `oQuery = (NameValueCollection)requestContext.HttpContext.Request.GetType().GetField("_form", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(requestContext.HttpContext.Request);`

Comment: Do u just want to add data to your request or what are you trying to do? I don't understand what you're trying to do in the edit at all (I'm not Jon Skeet though so that might be why).

Comment: Are you sure you need that? Because when using MVC you shouldn't need to deal with `Form` collection or any of the `Request` for that matter. Your actions receive their arguments as function parameters, not as form values or query strings.

Comment: I want do like this: controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Add("name","value"); but i don't have ability to do that because Request.Form is read-only, that why i tried add values to Request.From through reflection.

Comment: I know that it is crazy idea, but i not have a choise, i try to write module to external existing system which validate some Request.Form values.

Comment: Why not just write to the underlying stream?

Answer (score 0):

Build up your Data before you add it to the post.

You'll need to add the data to the request's stream something like this should work:

```
using(HttpWebRequest myHttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl)
{
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myFormData);
   Stream requestStream = null;
   try
   {
      myHttpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
      requestStream = myHttpRequest.GetRequestStream();
      requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   }
}
```

The you may need to change the Encoding type but hopefully this should help you out, unless I totally got your question wrong.